# "Include Other Layout" causes build to fail in emulator. No errors or associated warnings

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I've added a couple small relative layouts to the main layout of an activity using "Include Other Layout" in the graphical editor.  However, for some reason when I try to load the activity in the emulator, it fails.  There are no warnings other than a bunch of generic stuff in LogCat that looks exactly the same as any other time I have an error.  In the .Java file for this activity, I've successfully made reference to the views within these included layouts without any problems.

This are the elements from the activity's .xml file that include the layouts.

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblParklandAssistDesc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblParklandAssistDesc"
    layout="@layout/parklandweight" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/parklandbsa" />
```

And these are the layouts that are included

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnWeightUp"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/Up" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/brnWeightDown"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnWeightUp"
    android:text="@string/Down" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblParklandWeightTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnWeightUp"
    android:text="@string/lblWeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblParklandWeightTitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnWeightUp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="100" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblParklandWeightTitle" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/lb" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/kg" />
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then the other one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBSADown"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnBSAUp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnBSAUp"
    android:text="@string/Down" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblParklandBSAtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="58dp"
    android:text="@string/lblParklandBSAtitle"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBSAUp"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/Up" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtBSA"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblParklandBSAtitle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblParklandBSAtitle"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't have the foggiest idea as to what could be going on or frankly even where to look.  I've been working with eclipse and java with android for almost two weeks, have made one app, and have been having great luck and easy learning with everything.  This has left me stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

New Addition(added .Java Content because it seems that the xml layouts themselves may not be the problem):

In the top of the activity's class I declare the variables that will handle the other layouts like this:

```
View parklandWeight;
View parklandBSA;
```

Then, when I assign the object to it - I do so like this:

```
parklandWeight = (View) findViewById(R.layout.parklandweight);
parklandBSA = (View) findViewById(R.layout.parklandbsa);
```

The only error that appears to be from this activity.java in the LogCat occurs just after this second assignment.  On another assignment that refers a button inside one of these layouts:

```
btnWeightUp = (Button) parklandWeight.findViewById(R.id.btnWeightUp);
```

Could this be the root of my issue?  I've read at least five or six different threads here in StackOverflow where this is what is advised to do.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried these code runs perfect... Try these.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:ignore="HardCodedText" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/top" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnWeightUp"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include2"
    android:text="Up" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/brnWeightDown"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnWeightUp"
    android:text="Down" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblParklandWeightTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnWeightUp"
    android:text="lblWeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblParklandWeightTitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnWeightUp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="100" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblParklandWeightTitle" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="lb" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="kg" />
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Mr. Gajjar.  I'm still having this issue.  I'm beginning to wonder if there's not a bug somewhere in the environment.  Because I spent most of the evening and night reading and rereading all the documentation I could find and can still find no reason for the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I was typing the variables for the layouts wrong.  Instead of using

```
View layoutVariable;
```

I needed to be typing by the actual layout type as below.

```
RelativeLayout parklandWeight;
RelativeLayout parklandBSA;
```

Then, when assigning the actual layout object to the variable, I should have been typing it as the layout type, of course.  But, more than that, in the findViewById method I was using R.layout.layout_id when I should have been using R.id.layout_id.  I was also referring to the xml file name where I should have been referring to the same +id that is used in the include tag in the xml file.
This is the way I should have been doing it:

```
parklandWeight = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.include1);
parklandBSA = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.include2);
```

I hope this helps any newcomers to android development who run into the same problem.  I hope you all have an incredible day!